# Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Can any one help me with the regular expression that

1. Should not contain 9 digits(123456789 or 123-45-6789).
2. Should accept underscore (_), hyphen (-), period (.) or at symbol (@).

Currently I am having two regular expressions to validate each step separately. How can we combine these two coditions

1. ^((?!([0-9]{3,3}-[0-9]{2,2}-[0-9]{4,4})|[0-9]{9}).)*$
2. ^[_-.@]+$

Examples:

Valid Strings :

1. testUser
2. testUser038
3. testUser038@, testUser@., testUser-, etc (Any combination of @-_.)
4. 038testUser

Invalid Strings :

1. testUser123456789
2. 123456789
3. 123-45-6789
4. testUser123-45-6789
5. testUser^ (Other special characters other than (@-_.))

Comment: Try `^(?!.*(?:[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{9})).*[_.@-].*$` if the second requirement is actually "the string must contain any of the four special chars".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This did not worked.  Example : test@12345678 should accept and test@123456789 should not accept.

Comment: So other pattern with 9 digits are allowed? Basically any pattern with an arbitrary number of digits along with those special characters other than the two patterns you have mentioned? Or are there any other restrictions? A minimum of numbers? Special characters after eachother allowed? I guess, what I'm trying to ask if you can elaborate a little on what it is you are after =)

Comment: Then what do you need? `.` already matches any char but line break chars. `^(?!.*(?:[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{9})).*$` should work for you (or your first regex).

Comment: @JvdV  Valid Strings :
1. testUser
2. testUser038
3. testUser038@, testUser@., testUser-, etc (Any combination of @-_.)
4. 038testUser

Invalid Strings :
1. testUser123456789
2. 123456789
3. 123-45-6789
4. testUser123-45-6789
5. testUser^ (Other special characters other than (@-_.))

Comment: Your attempted regex did not even closely reflect these specifics. Please update your question accordingly for users to come up with answers that reflect your actual need. See [ask] a question with a [mcve].

Comment: @JvdV I just updated the question

Comment: The two answers to date have interpreted "Should not contain 9 digits" differently. @Hans, with his rather nice regex, interpreted that to mean that the string should not contain "9 or more digits", which is the correct literal interpretation; I assumed you meant the string should not contain "exactly 9 digits", based in part on your examples. Unfortunately, a clarification would make one of our answers incorrect. I don't know what, if anything, should be done in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could validate the string with the following regular expression.

```
(?i)^(?![^\d\n]*(?:\d[^\d\n]*){9}$)[a-z\d_.@-]*$
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/9WPcCF/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?i)          : invoke case-indifferent mode
^             : match beginning of string       
(?!           : begin a negative lookahead
  [^\d\n]*    : match 0+ chars other than digits and newlines
  (?:         : begin non-capture group
    \d        : match a digit
    [^\d\n]*  : match 0+ chars other than digits and newlines
  )           : end non-capture group
  {9}         : execute non-capture group 9 times
  $           : match end of string
)             : end negative lookahead
[a-z\d_.@-]*  : match 0+ chars in character class
$             : match end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var re =new Regex("^([[a-zA-Z_@.-]*[0-9]){0,8}[[a-zA-Z_@.-]*$");

var strings = new[] { "testUser",
"testUser038",
"testUser038@", "testUser@.", "testUser-",
"038testUser",
"testUser123456789",
"123456789",
"123-45-6789",
"testUser123-45-6789",
"testUser^"
};

foreach (var x in strings
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Value = s,
        IsMatch = re.IsMatch(s),
    }))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.IsMatch}: {x.Value}");
}
```

prints:

```
True: testUser
True: testUser038
True: testUser038@
True: testUser@.
True: testUser-
True: 038testUser
False: testUser123456789
False: 123456789
False: 123-45-6789
False: testUser123-45-6789
False: testUser^
```

## Explanation:

The regex searches for zero to 8 digits, optionally preceded by any number of letters (lower case or upper case) or specific symbols. The pattern is optionally followed by (again) any number of letters and/or those symbols.
That "any number" can also be zero.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me and this a great explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
^(?=(?:[-_.@a-z]*\d){0,8}[-_.@a-z]*$)[-_.@a-z\d]+$
```

with *g*, *m* and *i* options

Details:

- `^` - Start of a line (*m* option).
- `(?=` - Start of positive lookahead (check the current line for max.
  8 digits, with other allowed chars before / between / after them).

  - `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.

    - `[-_.@a-z]*` - Possibly empty sequence of allowed chars (also capital
      letters) except of digits.
    - `\d` - A digit.
  - `){0,8}` - End of a non-capturing group, this group can occur up to 8 times.
  - `[-_.@a-z]*` - Another (possibly empty) sequence of allowed chars
    except of digits (after the last allowed digit).
  - `$` - End of line - no other content allowed in the current line.
- `)` - End of positive lookahead.
- `[-_.@a-z\d]+` - The content to match - a non-empty sequence of allowed chars.
- `$` - End of line.

To put it short:

- The positive lookahead checks for max. 8 digits in the current line.
- Then `[...]` matches the allowed content, up to the end of line.

Note also such important difference to your regex: After `[` (opening
a character class) the **first** char is `-`, so this way it is treated
**literally**. You put `-` **in the middle**, so it acts as "from - to"
condition (wrong).

For a working example see: https://regex101.com/r/yniJl4/1